# Templated class with a non-template base gives me a LNK2005 error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, lnk2005

I have a templated class **Child** which inherits from a non-templated **Parent** class.  When I include **Child**'s header in multiple .cpp files I get a LNK2005 error.  This happens because **Parent** gets defined in multiple compilation units.  When those units get linked together they cause the LNK2005 error.

In case you're wondering, the purpose of **Parent** is to give **Child** one static variable for all **Child** instance, not just one for each **Child< ''type'' >**.

My question is, how do I create a templated class which has a unique (across all **Child** instances) static variable and can be included in multiple .cpp files?

Here's a toy example that causes this LNK2005 error:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Apple.h"
#include "Banana.h"

#include <string>

void main() {
    Apple apple;
    Banana banana;
}
```

**Apple.h**

```
#ifndef APPLE_H
#define APPLE_H

struct Apple {
    Apple();
};

#endif // APPLE_H
```

**Apple.cpp**

```
#include "Apple.h"
#include "Child.h"

Apple::Apple() {
    Child<int> child;
    child.foo(5);
}
```

**Banana.h**

```
#ifndef BANANA_H
#define BANANA_H

struct Banana {
    Banana();
};

#endif // BANANA_H
```

**Banana.cpp**

```
#include "Banana.h"
#include "Child.h"

Banana::Banana() {
    Child<double> child;
    child.foo(3.14);
}
```

**Child.h**

```
#ifndef CHILD_H
#define CHILD_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

///////////// Parent Class Def ///////////

class Parent {
    protected:
    static int id;
};

int Parent::id = 0;

///////////// Child Class Def ///////////

template <class T>
struct Child : protected Parent {
    Child();
    void foo(T t);
};

template <class T>
Child<T>::Child() {
    id++;
}

template <class T>
void Child<T>::foo(T t) {
    cout << "Child" << id << "'s foo() says: " << t << endl;
}

#endif // CHILD_H
```

error LNK2005: "protected: static int Parent::id" (?id@Parent@@1HA) already defined in Apple.obj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define `int Parent::id = 0;` just once in `Child.C`. By including it in the header it gets defined once per file that includes your header.

I suppose I should note that between the evils of putting it in `Parent.C` (matching class name) or `Child.C` matching the header name, I picked consistency. Much better is to put `Parent` in its own files so that you can put the definition in an aptly named `Parent.C` which still matches the corresponding header name.

Comment: I think I need to learn to type faster.. +1 for exactly that. :P

Comment: Ahh I should have thought of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pull

```
int Parent::id = 0;
```

out into `Parent.cpp` and you 'll be fine. What happens now is that the definition gets included once per translation unit that includes `Child.h`.